# getting property of circular socket object nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets, properties

So, I have this strange problem: First, I connect to a socket like this:

`window.GLOBAL_socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');`

Then, if I print out the window.GLOBAL_socket variable, I get a circular variable which contains the property 'connected' which is set true if the connection is succesfull, and false if it isn't as seen in the google chrome console. But when I write the following:

`console.log(window.GLOBAL_socket.connected);`

It always returns 'false'. Anyone has a clue why this doesn't change?
(same happens with the property 'disconnect'; changes when I print out the entire variable, but stays 'true' when printing out the property.

Kind regards,

Zeno

Comment: By `write the following` do you mean write it in your source file or in google chrome console?

Comment: What is a "circular variable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're printing it out too early. It's not connected yet. Therefore what you printed out is correct - it's not connected.

The reason it works form the console is because by the time you type in the console it's already connected.

To prove this, print it out at a later time:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(window.GLOBAL_socket.connected);
},5000); // hopefully 5 seconds is long enough to connect
         // adjust this as necessary
```

Or you can keep logging until it's connected:

```
var connect_check = setInterval(function(){
    console.log(window.GLOBAL_socket.connected);
    if (window.GLOBAL_socket.connected) {
        clearInterval(connect_check);
    }
},10); // do this 100 times per second
```

Another way to execute a function at a later time is to attach it to an onclick event:

```
<button id="log">Log Connected Status</button>
<script>
    document.getElementById('log').onclick = function(){
        console.log(window.GLOBAL_socket.connected);
    };
</script>
```

Of course, you can simply use socket.io connection event:

```
GLOBAL_socket.on('connection',function(){
    // But then the following is redundant because we KNOW
    // it's connected because we're in this event handler.
    console.log(window.GLOBAL_socket.connected);
});
```